# C++, modify value on the heap VS delete and new

Tags: c++, heap-memory

In a class example in a C++ book, there is an overloading of the assignment operator with the following lines:

```
delete m_pName;
m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
```

What is wrong with, instead, simply change the value in the already allocated space?

```
*m_pName = *(c.m_pName);
```

Thank you.

Comment: At first glance, nothing. There is also almost certainly no point in having a `string*` member variable instead of a plain `string` in the first place. If your book's author doesn't explain why they do what they do, you might want to look for a better book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. In fact I would use it.

I would even question why there is a `std::string*`, why isn't it a `std::string` or a `std::optional<std::string>`?

The only difference that I see is that the original code makes sure that the memory is freed and freshly allocated. Your approach might reuse alloacted memory and not free up extra space that was allocated and that is now not needed anymore (because the new string is shorter).

Side note: having raw owning pointers is not modern C++. Better use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I would change `having raw pointers is not modern` in something like `having raw owing pointers is not modern`. The first one often leads - for people with less c++ knowledge - to the assumption, that raw pointers are bad in general in modern c++.

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong with, instead, simply change the value in the already allocated space?

It does a (slightly) different thing. If that different thing isn't what the function is supposed to do, then it's the wrong thing to do.

So, it boils down to what you're trying/supposed to do. That determines whether what you're doing is wrong or correct. Given that you haven't described what you're trying to do, it is unclear why you think the suggested function would be wrong.

---

P.S. Avoid bare owning pointers. Prefer RAII classes such as smart pointers or containers instead.

P.P.S. Avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation. There's hardly ever a need to dynamically allocate a `std::string`.

So in conclusion, perhaps what you should actually be using is something like the following:

```
struct example {
    std::string name;
};
```

Note that the assignment operator is generated implicitly.